# Table column with another table

Tags: html, css, angularjs, html-table

I have to make a table with a column having another table but I want colors to be different  of each alternating row. Image is given below:(Ignore character again column)
[image: sample image]

Please find below the angularJS sample table code: (List can have any number of elements i.e even or odd )

```
<table style="border: 1px solid;">
<thead>
  <th>Character</th>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>CharacterAgain</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
           <tr ng-repeat="actor in AAA.cast">
            <td>{{actor.character}}</td>
<td>
  <table>
   <tr ng-repeat="actor1 in AAA.cast"> // could be some another list
      <td>
     {{actor.name}}
     </td>

   </tr>
  </table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I have tried many alternatives to assign the CSS class through script but they are failing in one or the other cases. I would be very thankful if anyone can give me working jsFiddle for this. Please let me know if this is possible by CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Its really simple, in your css file just add

```
tr:nth-child(even) {background: #CCC}
tr:nth-child(odd) {background: #FFF}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/x8vxhuhk/

If you needed to ensure this only happened on the inner table, you could either add a class to the whole table, i.e.

HTML:

```
<table class='striped'>
```

CSS:

```
.striped tr:nth-child(even) {background: #CCC}
.striped tr:nth-child(odd) {background: #FFF}
```

Or if you didn't have access to alter the classes something a little muckier like:

CSS:

```
table table tr:nth-child(even) {background: #CCC}
table table tr:nth-child(odd) {background: #FFF}
```

Support is pretty good, with the only question marks being IE8
http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3

#### Edit

So, you could do:

```
/* Outer table */
table tr:nth-child(even) {background: #FFF}
table tr:nth-child(odd) {background: #CCC}
/* Inner table */
table table tr:nth-child(even) {background: #CCC}
table table tr:nth-child(odd) {background: #FFF}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer... but kindly see the table structure..I had already applied the logic u gave me..but I want 2nd row's 1'st column color to be opposite of 1st rows last column(This column contains another table). The above logic gives me same color for that.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `nth-of-type` selector:

```
.tr{
   background: blue;
}

.tr:nth-of-type(odd){
   background: black; 
}
```